# error: type ‘class’ is not a direct base of ‘class’

Tags: c++, class, constructor, radix, derived-class

I haven't been able to find an answer that relates specifically to my question. It's a bit of a "strange" case in terms of what I've seen.

So I have a class `Child2` that inherits from `Child1` that in turn inherits from the `Parent`. The `Parent` doesn't have a constructor.

Here is how I inherit:

**Child1.h:**

```
class Child1 : virtual public Parent
```

This is the function that I want to call from `Child2`'s constructor:

```
void Child1::foo(unsigned int i)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Child2**

```
Child2::Child2() : Child1()
{
   foo(10);
}
```

There are no functions called `foo()` in `Child2` so there shouldn't be any ambiguity if I understand correctly.

However, I encounter this error:

> Child2.cpp: In constructor ‘Child2::Child2()’:
>    Child2.cpp:12:28: error: type ‘Child1’ is not a direct base of ‘Child2’
>    Child2::Child2() : Child1()

`Child1`'s constructor is working, so I've left it out. I'm not certain if it is important in this case.

Comment: You've left out plenty that may be important in this case.   You need to provide an [mcve].    After all, if you don't know what the problem is, how do you know that stuff you've left out isn't what other people need to be able to help you?

Comment: Please share declaration of `foo` function.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Child2 class is declared as a child of Child1. Something like:

```
class Child2 : Child1 
{....}
```